# грани куба в open cv

Tags: python, opencv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, не понимаю, как с помощью open cv определить и  выделить грани этого куба??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то, это довольно просто.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.png') 
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3,3), 0) 

edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=0, threshold2=100)

cv2.imshow("Result", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: -]

Comment: Вообще-то это называется выделить ребра куба, а не грани.  Для выделения граней нужно следующим этапом инвертировать и найти связные компоненты. cv2.connectedComponentWithStats(). Нулевой компонент это будет фон, а остальные - грани.